# SwiftMailer not sending emails in Symfony 2.5

Tags: php, email, symfony, swiftmailer

After spending 2 days trying to get it to work, I finally decided to ask here. I am trying to generate an email once the user submits the contact form, upon reading the documentation on Symfony [website](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html#full-default-configuration) and countless other articles on stackoverflow and google I just cant get it to work. Looking at the instruction it looks like it should be pretty straight forward but none of the solutions are working. I tried sending emails via Gmail and via our company SMTP but both did not work

This is my current `parameters.yml`

```
swiftmailer:
   transport:            smtp
   username:             username (confirmed that i am entering it right)
   password:             password (confirmed that i am entering it right)
   host:                 mail.domain.com
   port:                 26
   auth_mode:            login
```

The above setting does not give any error, it just submits the form and displays success message but no mails are recieved

I even tried several other combination like the one below using Gmail but this returns user authentication error, I made sure over and over and over that I am entering the right login details and 100% sure they are correct because via browser i can login.

**config.yml:**

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: %mailer_transport%
    encryption: %mailer_encryption%
    auth_mode:  %mailer_auth_mode%
    host:      %mailer_host%
    username:  %mailer_username%
    password:  %mailer_password%
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

**parameters.yml:**

```
mailer_transport:  smtp
mailer_encryption: ssl
mailer_auth_mode:  login
mailer_host:       smtp.gmail.com
mailer_username: myusername@gmail.com
mailer_password: mypassword
```

This is what my controller looks like which is generating email

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $enquiry = new Enquiry();
        $form = $this->createForm(new EnquiryType(), $enquiry);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject('Contact enquiry')
                ->setFrom('username@domain.com')
                ->setTo('username@domain.com')
                ->setBody(
                    $this->renderView('ContactBundle:Default:contactEmail.txt.twig', array('enquiry' => $enquiry))
                );
            //print_r($message);
            $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
                'notice',
                'Your contact enquiry was successfully sent. Thank you!'
            );

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('contact_form'));
        }

        return $this->render(
            'ContactBundle:Default:contact.html.twig',
            array(
                'form' => $form->createView()
            )
        );

    }
```

I will really appreciate if I can get some help here as I am completely clueless right now.

Comment: First, check your configuration using symfony console. You should have command swiftmailer:email:send
Second, if you are using gmail.com to send mail, please change transport

Comment: I can see the email in profiler and i even get it when i add `delivery_address` in config.yml, which is meant to test email, but it is not working when i remove it

Comment: i tried changing `mailer_transport` to `gmail` when trying to send mails via Gmail but that did not help either

Comment: Is there a firewall between your web server and your SMTP server ?

Comment: I have replaced the `->setTo('username@domain.com')` to another email id and emails are now being received just fine, server admin is looking into whatever the problem is with email id mentioned before. However Gmail problem still exist, cant send emails via Gmail

Comment: Comment out the spool parameter in config.yml and see if that helps.

Comment: Finally got it to work, I have added the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it to work on both company based SMTP and Gmail

For company SMTP

**config.yml:**

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: %mailer_transport%
    encryption: %mailer_encryption%
    auth_mode:  %mailer_auth_mode%
    host:      %mailer_host%
    username:  %mailer_username%
    password:  %mailer_password%
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

**parameters.yml:**

```
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: mail.domain.com
    mailer_user: username@domain.com
    mailer_password: password
```

For Gmail `config.yml` settings remain the same but in `parameters.yml` make the following change

```
    mailer_transport: gmail
    mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
    mailer_user: username@gmail.com
    mailer_password: password
```

Then visit this [link](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) of google to allow apps to login into your account to send mails.
You can also view any suspecious activity of login using this [link](https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity?pli=1)

**Note:**

In your controller where you are telling the function to send email `->setFrom('username@gmail.com')` should match the email id which is generating the email otherwise you will not get an email, I over looked this and wasted 2 days on it.

```
 $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject('Contact enquiry')
                ->setFrom('username@gmail.com') \\match this to mailer_user in parameters.yml
                ->setTo('username@gmail.com')
                ->setBody(
                    $this->renderView('ContactBundle:Default:contactEmail.txt.twig', array('enquiry' => $enquiry))
                );
```

This is how I got it work :) finally, hopefully this will help someone out there stuck. I can confirm that this solution works for me on both development and production server.

Comment: *"should match the email id which is generating the email"* That's a limitation of your SMTP server, not SwiftMailer. If your SMTP server permits spoofing (e.g. Mandrill, SendGrid, etc) then it's absolutely fine for the `username` and `from address` to be different. Swiftmailer's debugging flags can be really useful here, as can your logs.

Comment: Along with your answer, what most helped me was the comment you made: "match this to mailer_user in parameters.yml". This was the actual reason of not working.