# SwiftMailer not send mail with Google App account

Tags: email, symfony, gmail, google-apps, swiftmailer

I'm using Symfony and I'm trying to send an email with swiftmailer. I have an account set up with google app (produccion@mydomain.com) and when I try to send shows me the following error:

> Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username
>   "produccion@mydomain.com" using 2 possible authenticators

I tried it with my personal gmail account and send the message correctly with the same settings. Just change the username and password.

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: smtp
    host:      smtp.gmail.com
    username:  produccion@mydomain.com   #email@gmail.com
    password:  google_app_password       #gmail_password
    auth_mode: login
    port:      587
    encryption: tls
```

I've been searching the internet and I've found this page from Google, where I can change the access to less secure applications.
https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

In my gmail account this option is active, but if I turn shows me the same error when sending email.
I've been trying to change this setting in google app account but it tells me that this option is not available for google app.

Any idea to send emails from this account by google app? I have to set something else?

**EDIT**
It seems Gmail prefers OAuth, Swiftmailer supports this authentication mech but its not really documented.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/xoauth2_protocol
https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/5.x/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/Esmtp/Auth/XOAuth2Authenticator.php

Any idea how I use it in Symfony?

Comment: The option linked is consumer accounts only I believe. I recommend using Google's SMTP relay service detailed at https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491 when looking to set up this kind of thing with Apps.

Comment: might want to check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26018224/swiftmailer-not-sending-emails-in-symfony-2-5/26020753#26020753

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the transport parameter to gmail as mentioned in the cookbook? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/gmail.html

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: gmail
    username:  your_gmail_username
    password:  your_gmail_password
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried it but it's the same configuration that I use in my example.