# SwiftMailer doesn't work symfony2

Tags: symfony, contacts, swiftmailer

I have done a ContactBundle in my website with symfony2 but it doesn't work i don"t how it works ..
my controller :

```
namespace Common\ContactBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Common\ContactBundle\Form\ContactType;

class ContactController extends Controller {

public function indexAction() {

    //Création du formulaire
    $form = $this->createForm(new ContactType());


    //L'envoi du message
    if ($form->isValid()) {

        $name = $form['name']->getData();
        $email = $form['email']->getData();
        $tel = $form['tel']->getData();
        $message = $form['message']->getData();


        $final_message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject('NasriCenter : message de contact ')
                ->setFrom($email)
                ->setTo('thamer.nasri@gmail.com')
                ->setBody($this->renderView('ContactBundle:Contact:email.html.twig', array(
                    'name' => $name,
                    'email' => $email,
                    'tel' => $tel,
                    'message' => $message
                        )
        ));

        $this->get('mailer')->send($final_message);
    }

    //Affichage du formulaire
    return $this->render('ContactBundle:Contact:index.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
    }

 }
```

my file parameters :

```
mailer_transport:  smtp
mailer_encryption: ssl
mailer_host:       smtp.gmail.com
mailer_user:       thamer.nasri@gmail.com
mailer_password:   null
```

my config file is i token this configuration from a video in youtube

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: smtp
    encryption: "%mailer_encryption%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     
        type: file
        path: "%kernel.root_dir%/spool"
```

can you help me plz to solve this error

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26018224/swiftmailer-not-sending-emails-in-symfony-2-5/26020753#26020753

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have desactivated my antivirus

Answer (score 0):

The configuration files and the controller action looks okay. Since you have enabled spool, make sure that the spool directory is writable.  Also, to send the spooled mails, you would need to run the following command.

```
$ php app/console swiftmailer:spool:send --env=prod
```

Since you are getting authentication error with Google, please verify that you have allowed login from less secure apps for the account that you are using. Please refer to the following

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en