# Symfony2, send mail to gmail

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I want to intercept all email send by Symfony2.

I configure swiftmailer like that:

```
swiftmailer:
    delivery_address: my@gmail.com #My gmail addr
    transport: gmail
    username:  my@gmail.com#I use my gmail for easy smtp configuration (just for dev)
    password:  mypassword
```

I receive no emails. I'm developping on Windows10 and i use Wamp.

Comment: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26020753)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you in dev mode, so you need to do this in you config_dev file:

```
# app/config/config_dev.yml
swiftmailer:
    disable_delivery: false
    delivery_address:  dev@example.com
```

Answer (score -2):

I guess you put your conf in config.yml file. You have to check in config_prod and config_dev if the "delevery_address" param is not overidden.